# NoMethodError in Rails despite defining Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I successfully completed Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial, and I'm now working on my first more independent web development project. I've read other NoMethodError Q&A on StackOverflow, but so far nothing is helping.

I am re-using a concept Hartl covered, specifically defining a customer helper called `full_title`.  I've put the follwoing code in `/app/helpers/application_helper.rb`:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def full_title(page_title)
    base_title = 'BaseTitle Text'
    if page_title.empty?
      base_title
    else
      "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
    end
  end
end
```

Then in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`, I've put this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

With these tests in `spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb`, I get a `NoMethodError / undefined method`.

```
it "should have the right links on the layout" do
    visit root_path
    click_link "About"
    page.should have_selector 'title', text: full_title('About')
    click_link "Contact"
    page.should have_selector 'title', text: full_title('Contact')
```

I'm not quite sure why there's no Method being recognized here.

Fyi I'm using Capybara 1.1.2, in case that matters.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What error do you get exactly?

Comment: `1) StaticPages Home page should have the right links on the layout
     Failure/Error: page.should have_selector 'title', text: full_title('About')
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `full_title' for `<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x007fc2692d7d40>
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:19:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should try to include your helper module in your spec.

```
include ApplicationHelper
```

Or if you use **RSpec** you can include modules like this:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ...
  config.include ApplicationHelper
end
```

Comment: This worked!!  I did look at my code from `/views/spec_helper.rb` the sample_app in Hartl's book, and I noticed that there was this code:

    `require 'rubygems'
     require 'spork'
     Spork.prefork do
     end
     Spork.each_run do
  end`   

When I pasted that over, that didn't work, and I realize I probably have some additional config of `spork` to do there.  In meantime, your suggestion helped greatly.  Many Thanks!